# How to solve error in passing variables to SQL query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, file-handling

I have a list of existing tables in database, I need to update existing tables with csv files...
So what I have done is...

1. I have created temp tables in database and I have inserted the values from csv files to the temp tables in database.
2. then I have made two lists, one list consists of existing tables and other list consists of temp table.
3. I created my temp tables with prefixed existing tables names ending with temp eg. tablenametemp, so that I can match with existing tables.
4. once i found the match then I will update the existing tables with the temp tables with matching primary keys.
5. if the primary key already exists the I will update the existing records ELSE I will insert it as a new record to the table
6. once all done temp tables are removed
   here is the code which I have done..

   for a in list_table:
   if a+'temp' in list_temp:

   ```
        pk = engine.execute('''
                                    SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME 
                                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T  
                                    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = T.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
                                    WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = ? 
                                    AND T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'  ''',a)

        pk_temp = engine.execute('''
                                    SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME 
                                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T  
                                    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = T.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
                                    WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = ? 
                                    AND T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'  ''',a+"temp")

        col = engine.execute('''
                                    SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?  ''',a)
        col_temp = engine.execute('''
                                    SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?  ''',a+"temp")

        sql_merge = engine.execute("""
        MERGE %s Target
        USING %s AS Source
        ON Source.%s = Target.%s
        /* new records ('right match') */
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
        INSERT (%s)
        VALUES (Source.%s)
        /* matching records ('inner match') */
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
        Target.%s = Source.%s
        /* deprecated records ('left match') */
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
        DELETE
        ;
        """, (a, a + "temp", pk, pk_temp, col, col_temp, col, col_temp))

        engine.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ? """, a + "temp")
   ```

when I execute this code I got the error like this

**
'The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 8 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'
**

I think this error is thrown when I execute the sql_merge query, and I really got no idea of how to solve this, Please help me

Comment: I don't fully understand your code, cos I'm not a Python expert, but it seems you are trying to parameterise the table name and the column name in your statements, which you cannot do, because SQL is a static language.

Comment: as i need to do this with 3k or 4k tables so, I am trying in this way... is there any other way to do

Comment: Dynamic SQL....

Answer (score -2):

change your parameter marker from `%s` to `?` in the sql_merge.

Comment: when I try with "?" , it is giving other error like this, 'Invalid parameter type.  param-index=2 param-type=LegacyCursorResult', 'HY105'

Comment: thats is because you are passing a wrong parameter type. try to convert the parameters to string. FYI this is a different problem. my first solution solved your original problem.

Comment: where i need to convert in my code

Comment: sql_merge = engine.execute(""" MERGE ? Target
        USING ? AS Source ON Source.? = Target.?
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
        INSERT (?) VALUES (Source.?)
        /* matching records ('inner match') */
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
        Target.? = Source.?
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
        DELETE
        ;
        """, str((a, a + "temp", pk, pk_temp, col, col_temp, col, col_temp))) I have done like this, when execute this, I got error like "'The SQL contains 8 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000'"

Comment: your parameters are a, a+"temp",pk,pk_temp..
so it becomes str(a), str(a+"temp"),str(pk)...
but you only need to do this for parameters with non string type.